# Let $\sum a_n=s$ be conditional convergent, $\sum a_{f(n)}=t\neq s$. Show $\forall\ N, \exists\ n$, such that $|n-f(n)|>N$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

Let $\sum a_n=s$ be conditional convergent, $\sum a_{f(n)}=t\neq s$. Show $\forall\ N, \exists\ n$, such that $|n-f(n)|>N$.

Here, $f: \Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is a bijection.

How to prove?

My attempt. Let the partial sums of $\sum a_n$ and $\sum a_{f(n)}$ be $s_n,t_n$. 
Argue by contradiction. If $\exists\ M>0$, such that for any $n$, $|n-f(n)|\leq M$. Then for $n>M$, $a_1,\cdots,a_{n-([M]+1)}$ appears in $t_n$. Then how to estimate $|s_n-t_n|$?

Comment: what are $s,t$ ?

Comment: This should answer your question,  the contrapositive:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150964/prove-that-the-series-still-converges-under-a-permutation